# Salesforce and GMX email

Tags: email, support

A lot of my contacts have gmx email, and they are complaining that are not receving email sent directly from SF. Does Salesforce has any compability problem with GMX?

Comment: Have you taken any steps to debug this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they have. 
We opened a ticket with Salesforce and asked GMX. Here is the reply from GMX (translated):
*The email servers from Salesforce are trying to establish a a secure connection with outdated encryption techniques, which of course fails. 
Salesforce is aware of this problem.*

The answer from Salesforce support is, that their R&D team is working on it.

Comment: as of today the problem is partially solved. I used the Salesforce "Test Deliverability" (Setup -> Email Administration -> Test Deliverability) with a GMX address. Out of the 52 test emails sent from 52 different Salesforce servers, 36 was received by the GMX account. According to our support the Salesforce R&D are still working on it. We hope they will fix the remaining servers until Saturday.